# In the song title「ハレ晴レユカイ」(Hare Hare Yukai), why is the second ハ written as a kanji but not the first?

Tags: translation, kanji, nuances, katakana

This song title is translated as [Sunny Sunny Happiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Haruhi_Suzumiya_albums#Hare_Hare_Yukai) in English, so it seems that both "hare" are supposed to have the same meaning, and yet they're not written in the same way. Is this a play on word, a common thing to do, or just random?

Comment: I guess probably the first one comes from 涼宮**ハル**ヒ. 

According to [yahoo知恵袋](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1010971495), the name「ハルヒ」might be derived from ある日 : "one day", "some day" or 晴れの日 : "sunny day", etc.

The lyricist probably wants to use a bit of her name(ハレ）in the song title and use kanji(晴れ） is used after that( "日": radical of "晴" may be explaining the meaning of ハルヒ).